# Customizing/Hiding Pagination Nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to customize the Pagination Plugin's Navigation; the First, Prev, Page 1, Page 2, Next, Last. I want to make it 'Prev, Next, Page 1 of 2'

http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/

The documentation states I can hide 'First/Last' by declaring `show_first_last` as `false` -

However, this didn't work.

**UPDATE:** Here's a link with the full code, and struggle. http://tinyurl.com/buab7ah

Comment: do you have some html? or even a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Doesn't look like it's supported out of the box, but hey, my afternoon is free...

Comment: Success! It's now part of the plugin, so this issue shouldn't exist again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so it doesn't support it out of the box and I had to modify it a little. Here's the link:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24657596/Pajinate/jquery.pajinate.js

So how does it work? Simple - specify the order via a string array, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#paging_container1').pajinate({
        nav_order : ["prev", "next", "num"] 
    });
});
```

Or like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#paging_container1').pajinate({
        nav_order : ["prev", "next", "num", "first", "last"]    
    });
});
```